# Where to add StateStore in SpringBoot Kafka Stream

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, apache-kafka, topology

I'm trying to use the Topology Test Driver which requires the topology in its constructor.
However, while the application itself works fine it fails in my KStream unit tests with the following error:

```
"StateStore ... is already added"
```

Here's my KStream that I'd like to test (shortened):

```
@Bean
public KStream<...,...> kstream(StreamsBuilder builder) {
  builder.addStateStore(...);
  KStream<...,...> stream = builder.stream().filter(...).etc()
  stream.process(()->...);
  return stream;
}
```

My test (shortened)

```
def "..."() {
  given:
    ...
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    MyStreamService myStreamService = new MyStreamService(...stubbed);
    KStream mykStream = myStreamService.kStream(builder);
    TopologyTestDriver driver = new TopologyTestDriver(builder.build(), ...)
    ...
```

As soon as I run builder.build() to get the Topology it throws the above error - however I don't understand why as I'm only calling addStateStore once in that very place. I removed the entire stream logic except for the .addStoreStore() method to see if any of the other methods would initialize it (map, filter, process etc.) to no avail.

I understand there are other ways to test Kafka streams but I'm **specifically** trying to get it working the above explained way. If this is not possible that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

In the application.yml file try to add the following line:
spring:kafka:streams:state-dir: "dir-path"
kstreams will use the "dir-path" directory for state-stores.